# php mysql ajax live search array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays

I have an ajax live search script working except that it only seems to be returning the first row of the array.  Don't know if it is something with my loop, however, if anyone can spot error, would greatly appreciate help as I cannot seem to find it.  I am not including javascript cause I'm pretty sure that is not error as php file is firing.  It is just echoing the first hit and not iterating through others.

```
//run query on dbase then use mysql_fetch_array to place in array form
while($a = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
    if (strlen($q) > 0)
    {
        $hint="";
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
        {
            if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
            {
                $n = $a['first']." ".$a['last'];
                if ($hint=="")
                {
                    $hint='<a href="mailto.php">'.$n.'</a>'; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $hint=$hint.'<br><a href="mailto.php">'.$n.'</a>';// we do not seem to get here
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hints were found
// or to the correct values
}//close while fetch
echo $hint;
```

Comment: if you are trying to echo more than one hint then the `$hint` variable will be overwritten on each iteration of the loop? Try using `.=` instead, this will concatenate the values together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting your `$hint` variable on every `while` loop iteration. Try declaring it before the `while` (remove where you have it now)

```
$hint = "";
while($a = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_BOTH))
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method:

```
<?
$output = '';
while($a = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    if (strlen($q) > 0) {
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
            if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q)))) {
                $n = $a['first']." ".$a['last'];
                if ($output == "") {
                    $output = '<a href="mailto.php">'.$n.'</a>';
                } else {
                    $output .= '<br><a href="mailto.php">'.$n.'</a>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $output;
?>
```